# tk.update() doesn't remove previous line when a new one is drawn

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *
import math
tk=Tk()
canvas=Canvas(tk,width=810,height=600)
canvas.pack()

glass_parameters = [-200, 200]
glass_length = 1000
i_ray_start = 50
i_ray_end = 410
refractive_index = 1.5
angle = 0

def incident_ray(y1):
    angle1 = math.radians(angle)
    tangent_angle = math.tan(angle1)
    if angle >= 90:
        x1 = 0
    else:
        x1 = (glass_parameters[1]-y1)/tangent_angle
    canvas.create_line(i_ray_end-x1, y1, i_ray_end, glass_parameters[1])

def increase_incident_angle():
    global angle
    angle +=1
    tk.update()
    incident_ray(i_ray_start)
```

When the `increase_incident_angle()` function is called, my program draws a new line as expected. The only thing is that the old line is not deleted by `tk.update()`. I have tried `tk.update_idletasks()` but neither of these seem to work.

Comment: If you want to remove a line from a canvas you have to delete it.

Comment: Ahh okay - I'd though that updating erased all stuff you've drawn. Thanks, I found a quick way to do it by adding tag = 'line' to the create line and then calling canvas.delete('line') :)

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use  a class, you can also answer the question, marking it as solved is not how it works on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update doesn't remove anything, it only causes any pending events (including events which request the screen to be refreshed) to be performed. You must delete canvas items with the `delete` method.